# daysToTransaction and sessionToTransaction not working as expected

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to know the overall days to a transaction of the site also the sessions to transaction. But as these are dimesions AFAIK I can't get these results directly, so if I can get the rows with "days to transaction" and "transactions" then I will be able to calculate the average.

So I did this

```
var diasnecesarioscompra = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        query: {
            'start-date': startdate,
            'end-date': enddate,
            dimension: 'ga:daysToTransaction',
            metrics: 'ga:transactions'
        },
        chart: {
            container: 'diasnecesarioscompra',
            type: 'TABLE',
            options: {
                width: '100%'
            }
        }
    });
diasnecesarioscompra.execute();
```

Expecting this
[image]
(This is a custom report and I used the same dimension and metric as in the code.)

However with the code I just get one row with the sum of all transactions.

What's the proper way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, I had a typo on my code and Google just swallows 
it.

```
dimension -> dimensions
```